# ResponseEnd Time in Timing api

Tags: javascript, html, performance, navigation-timing-api

I am trying to measure page load performance using timing API. To start with I included below piece of code into body of my html document to check if I am getting all attributes correctly.

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
       console.log("navigationStart : "+  (performance.timing.navigationStart));
       console.log("responseStart : "+ (performance.timing.responseStart));
       console.log("responseEnd : "+ (performance.timing.responseEnd));
       console.log("domComplete : "+ (performance.timing.domComplete));
       console.log("loadEventStart : "+ (performance.timing.loadEventStart));
       console.log("LoadEventEnd : "+ (performance.timing.loadEventEnd));
     });
```

Output is below

navigationStart : 1538169000862
responseStart : 1538169000862
responseEnd : 1538169000862
domComplete : 1538169001831
loadEventStart : 1538169001831
LoadEventEnd : 0

I am wondering why LoadEventEnd is zero? Is it because page is still loading? what would be the best time to capture these metrics then?

Edit :-- After introducing timeout, I was able to capture LoadEvendEnd time. However when I move to next pages many of the attributes are zero now.

navigationStart : 1538172249035
responseStart : 1538172249035
responseEnd : 1538172249035
domComplete : 0
loadEventStart : 0
LoadEventEnd : 0

This navigation is inside a frame as i understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7606972/5247200. Have a look to the (current) [downmost answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11355758/5247200), it references the spec.

Comment: Thanks @David. After adding timeout I am getting excepted result.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - LoadEventEnd is zero because page is still loading.
You need to do the code after the page has loaded ...

```
window.addEventListener('load', loaded)
```

... is not enough because the load queue has not finished
The trick is to put your code back on the event queue ...

```
function loaded() {
  setTimeout(nowYouCanDoIt, 0)
}
```

... and check that loadEventEnd is not zero anymore:

```
function nowYouCanDoIt() {
  console.log("loadEventEnd: " + performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].loadEventEnd)
}
```